# Use cos and sin to get coordinates to use on canvas.createLineGradient

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following data structure that will paint a gradient in a canvas:

```json
{
    id: 'gold',
    degree: 133,
    colorStops: [
      [0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'],
      [0.09, 'rgba(48,37,27,1)'],
      [0.19, 'rgba(95,77,59,1)'],
      [0.50, 'rgba(223,223,223,1)'],
      [0.77, 'rgba(95,77,59,1)'],
      [0.94, 'rgba(48,37,27,1)'],
      [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'],
    ]
},
```

I'm trying to create a function that gets as an input the data above and draws the gradient on the canvas.

I get an angle in degrees and I would like to be able to calculate `x1 and y1` to use in [createLineGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient). I have used the [laws of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) but I'm not understanding where I went wrong to calculate the `x1 and y1` positions:

```js
function calculateX1Y1(angleDegree: number, x0: number, y0: number, canvaWidth: number) {
  const angleRadians = angleDegree * Math.PI / 180;

  let _x1 = canvaWidth * Math.cos(angleRadians);
  let _y1 = canvaWidth * Math.sin(angleRadians);

  return { _x1, _y1 };
}

export function paintGradient(
  canva: HTMLCanvasElement,
  gradient: GRADIENT_PAYLOAD,
  canvaWidth: number,
  canvaHeight: number,
) {
  const ctx = canva.getContext('2d')!;
  const x0 = 0;
  const y0 = 0;
  const {_x1, _y1} = calculateX1Y1(gradient.degree, x0, y0, canvaWidth);
  const canvasGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, _x1, _y1);

  gradient.colorStops.forEach(([offset, rgba]) => {
    canvasGradient.addColorStop(offset, rgba);
  });

  ctx.fillStyle = canvasGradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvaWidth, canvaHeight);

}
```

With this Im getting the following gradient:

[image]

The small one is the correct version (using `background: linear-gradient(...)`) while the wrong one is the big one being draw in the canva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because positive y is down by default in the canvas 2d context, so you are creating a gradient from the top left corner, toward a point that is further down and left. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdo7xpLy/) it works as you might expect by negating the y:

```
const oy = -Math.sin(angle) * canvasSize / 3;
```

Alternately, you could scale and translate the context so that positive y is up:

```
context.scale(1, -1);
context.translate(0, -canvasSize);
```